# File opens minimized in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

When I open any file (defaulted to Notepad++) then it opens in minimized condition, in the task bar. Is there any workarounds?

The only way I could do it, was [**Resetting Notepad++ settings**](https://superuser.com/a/540297/249349)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this setting on Normal window by default, still the problem occured.

What worked for me is changing it to Maximized window. Now any file that i open by right clicking Open with Notepad++, brings up Notepad++ in view rather than keeping it minimized on the taskbar.

Steps:

Right click on the Notepad icon, Properties, RUN AS: Maximized Window

Answer (score 4):

just done a few quick googles on this, if you can give this a try:
Right click on the Notepad icon, Properties, RUN AS: Normal Window

That seemed to have sorted it for quite a few others with notepad++

Answer (score 4):

What it seems to cause the problem is a combination of settings/actions.

Settings->Preferences->Multi-Instance->Default(mono-instance) allows only one instance to run. If this instance runs with Administrator privilleges, double click on txt files does not focus the window.

My own explanation for when I double clicked a txt file, notepad++ in Administrator-mode stayed in background, is that a double-click as a user-action is not considered an Administrative privilleged task therefore window with Administrative rights does not focus...

Solution: Either prevent yourself from initializing the only instance as Administrator, or open first time notepad++ by double-clicking a file (so that it will open in user mode), or enable multi-instance mode to allow more than a single window (with and without Administrator rights).

Worked for me, hope it works for you

Comment: I edited my hosts file and it restarted in administrator mode, when I restarted notepad++ it works as desired. (thanks, +1)

Comment: Nailed it! Changed my shortcut to no longer default to "Run as Administrator", reopened NP++, and files open normally now! Here's the [bug report](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3477).